# Facebook login auth issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I have followed the example of [Login for server-side apps](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) but for some reason `$_REQUEST['code']` is always blank. So I end up in an infinite loop of redirects for the dialog/oauth which I already agreed to so hence the endless loop. Anyone know what the problem might be?

If I echo out the `$_REQUEST` array I have "signed_request" and "PHPSESSID" in it that is all. Thanks in advance.

```
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
if (empty($code))
{
    // Create the CSRF protection
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

    // Set the permissions to request for
    // additionally from the standard user information
    // refer to documentation on other permissions
    //$request_permissions = "email,user_birthday";

    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $options['appId'] . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];
    echo "<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>";
}
```

**EDIT**: Also just a note: $code is populated in the url, just keeps refreshing... I have seen many people complain about this but it was well over a year ago and since I have tried all their steps as well as look at the SDK to see what is in there to help me and so far nothing seems to do the similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I notice: your variables to generate the `$dialog_url` aren't formatted correctly.

Try this:

```
$dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' . $options['appId'] . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($redirect_uri) . '&state=' . $_SESSION['state'] . '&scope=' . $request_permissions;
```

This is also more like the [Facebook Login for Server-side Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) page says...

Comment: Doesn't change anything... The url is populated with the &code=xyz but I cannot get xyz to do what I need. IF their is a work around to this I would love to read it cause I have wasted 5 hours on this issue already. Thank you though.

Comment: So, from what I get from this is, you receive a reply from Facebook and now you want to exchange the code for an access token?
It might be easier to use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) or the JavaScript library. Facebook offers an example app called [_Hackbook_](https://github.com/fbsamples/web-hackbook).

Comment: Yes basically... I'll check out the example app and see if my solution is there and I am confident it just might be since you linked it and know exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks. One Question though this example is only using JS is there something similar using PHP? Since that is my preferred language. Thanks again.